# I am just trying to run a function inside an object but it returns undefined output

Tags: javascript, object, this

```js
const rajat = {
  FirstName: "Rajat",
  middleName: "Kumar",
  lastName: "sahoo",
  birthYear: 1998,
  location: "Bhubaneswar",
  job: "Programmer",
  friends: ["Michel", "Jack", "James", "Juile"],

  calcAge: function () {
    this.Age = 2023 - this.birthYear;  // `here if i creat the age object it give undefine output`
    return this.Age;                   // `But when i normally call the function it works properly`
  },
};

console.log(rajat.Age);
```

I am just trying to calculate age using this method by creating an object but whenever i am trying to create the age object the output that I get is undefined why???

Comment: You haven't called `rajat.calcAge()`

Answer (score 1):

Consider making the `Age` a [getter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```js
const rajat = {
  FirstName: "Rajat",
  middleName: "Kumar",
  lastName: "sahoo",
  birthYear: 1998,
  location: "Bhubaneswar",
  job: "Programmer",
  friends: ["Michel", "Jack", "James", "Juile"],
  get Age() {
    return 2023 - this.birthYear;
  }
};

console.log(rajat.Age);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call rajat.Age() before printing it. Calling a function is like saying that you are going to use that function.